# CASE function in formula field says - Error: Incorrect argument type for function 'CASE()'

Tags: formula-field

What is missing in the below formula? I just copied it from the documentation and changed the fields and values.

```
CASE(
  IsAllDayEvent,
  true, "TRUE",
  false, "FALSE",
  ''
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the CASE() documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_case.htm&type=5)

> CASE functions can’t contain functions that return true or false. Instead, make true or false expressions return numbers

So the `true` and `false` values that you have for the second and fourth arguments are not valid.

Even if it were possible, this is one situation where using `IF()` makes more sense (and is less to type).
`IF(IsAllDayEvent, "True", "False")` is really all you need here, maybe adding in an `ISBLANK()` to the condition to handle nulls.